# how can i organize two plots with matplotlib pyplot in two columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have two plots:

```
vis.plot_positions_dlc(rois, tracking =tracking_data['ear_left'],
                    roi_colors = ['k','.3','orange','c','c','c','c','r','r','r','r'],
                    xlim=[0,800],ylim=[0,500],linewidth=4, ax=ax)
```

and

```
vis.plot_positions_dlc(rois, tracking =tracking_data['ear_left'],
                    roi_colors = ['k','.3','orange','c','c','c','c','r','r','r','r'],
                    xlim=[0,800],ylim=[0,500],linewidth=4, style=heatplot, ax=ax)
```

i want to simply create a plot where these two plots appear next to each other (i.e. one row two columns). how can i go about this?

Comment: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)` and then in the plot call `ax=ax1`, `ax=ax2`

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.